# Bridge mac learning ageing time

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Set ageing time by modifying "/sys/class/net/br0/bridge/ageing_time" to the maximum value.

```
# brctl showstp br0
br0
 bridge id      8000.001018000000
 designated root    8000.001018000000
....
 ageing time        4294314.45
....
```

but the learned table would be stale at the same time.

Check the codes, I saw something overflow in br_fdb.c

```
static inline int has_expired(const struct net_bridge *br,
                  const struct net_bridge_fdb_entry *fdb)
{
    return !fdb->is_static &&
        (time_before_eq(fdb->updated + hold_time(br), jiffies));
}
```

`fdb->updated + hold_time(br)` will be overflowed, then the learned table would be considered as timed out.

is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I guess so. But should not be a bug, just a inapropriate place.

If you want your non-static FDB entry never expired, but  it seems this overflow would cause has_expired() returns TRUE.

On a 32-bit machine, normally jiffies would wrap around every 50 days. That would also cause some trouble. But I guess sometimes some features are not tested that long.

On 32-bit machine, replace time_before_eq() with time_before_eq64(), and make some variables definition from "unsigned long" to "u64" should  work.  Of course, on 64-bit machine, every thing would be fine.